# ¿Cómo crear un combo que muestre años desde el actual hasta 1900?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este pequeño problema con `JavaScript` que no he logrado solucionarlo, necesito llenar las opciones de un selector de años de mi formulario, pero no quiero escribir todos los años manualmente, mas bien quiero que `JavaScript` lo haga por mi, desde el año actual hasta el año 1900, supuesta mente la función que estoy usando realiza esa tarea pero algo pasa que deja muchas opciones en blanco. Esta es la función:

```js
function loadPage(){
  ComboAno();
}
    
 function ComboAno(){
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getFullYear();
    var select = document.getElementById("ano");
    for(var i = n; i>=1900; i--){
        select.options[i]= new Option(i);
    }
}
```

```html
 <body onload="loadPage();">
        <form action="">
            
            <select name="" id="ano">
            </select>
                      
        </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crea un elemento `option`, añadele texto, su valor y agregalo al select.

```
function loadPage(){
     ComboAno();
 }

    function ComboAno(){

    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getFullYear();
    var select = document.getElementById("ano");
    for(var i = n; i >= 1900; i--) {
        var opc = document.createElement("option");
        opc.text = i;
        opc.value = i;
        select.add(opc)
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente! ahora comprendo muchas gracias, funcionò!

Comment: Puedes usar la solución de Dev Joel que es mas corta

Answer (score 1):

No tiene `options` en su `select` para asignar de la forma `select.options[i]` lo más sencillo que podría hacer es agregar una `option` haciendo uso de [select.options.add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add) , además puede emplear [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) para llamar a la función *(ComboAno)* y obtener el año directamente con `(new Date()).getFullYear()` sin crear otra variable.

```js
function ComboAno(){
   var n = (new Date()).getFullYear()
   var select = document.getElementById("ano");
   for(var i = n; i>=1900; i--)select.options.add(new Option(i,i)); 
};
window.onload = ComboAno;
```

```html
<select name="" id="ano"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto puede funcionar:

```
 $( función(){ 
     var d = new Date();
     var n = d.getFullYear();
     for(var i = n; i >=1900;i--)
          $("idselect").append("< option>"+i+"</option>");
 });
```

O

```
  <select>
    <script>
     var d = new Date();
     var n = d.getFullYear();
       for(var i = n; i >=1900; i--)
           document.write('<option>'+i+'</option>');
    </script>
 </select>
```

Comment: Si usas jquery puedes realizar:$( función(){ var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getFullYear();   for(var i = n; i >=1900;i--) $("idselect").append("< option>"+i+"</option>"); });

Comment: **Es una muy mala practica** emplear `document.write()`

Comment: Si! Por ello comente el uso de jquery

Comment: Puede emplear el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/109661/edit) y añadir el comentario a la respuesta. Saludos y gracias por contribuir.